# Redirect user to specific pages with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Im building a website with LAMP and i have a question about redirection users tha login to the page to a specific page for them.

Example.

If a company called XXX logged in to my page with their i want to redirect them to a specific site that no other companies will get access to.

As it is now, all the companies will get access to just one site...

Here is the code for my site:

```html
This is the login.php page.

$myusername= $_POST['user'];
$mypassword= $_POST['pass'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

 mysql_close();
 
 

 if($count==1) {
  $sekunder = 5 + time ();
   setcookie(inloggad, date("F jS - g:i a"), $sekunder);
  header("location:login_success.php");
  }
```

```html
This is the login_success.php page.

<?php


 if (!isset($_COOKIE['inloggad'])) {
  header("location:index.php");
  }
```

Thanks alot guys, cheers!

Comment: try `setcookie('inloggad', date("F jS - g:i a"), $sekunder);`

Comment: Your code is plainly wrong. First of all, you using stripslashes() while you should use addslashes() or even some other function which actually escapes the username and password before passing to the query. Next, your table column called 'password' is not good, that is a reserved word, you should call your table column differently. Finally ,setting a COOKIE on client side with the information that he is signed in is plainly wrong. Use $_SESSION instead to remember things about user (it will use cookies as well but only to pass session identifier)